# How to fix a File-Not-Found error on Workbooks.Open?

Tags: excel, vb6

So, this is the code that I need help with:

```
Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
If sPath = "" Then
    sPath = fWindowsTemp
End If

If sPath = "" Then
    sPath = "C:\"
End If

sArq = Dir(sPath & sNomeArquivo & "????." & sExtensao)
iNumero = 0

While sArq <> ""
    If Val(Mid(Replace(sArq, sNomeArquivo, "TEMP"), 5, 4)) >iNumero Then
        iNumero = Val(Mid(Replace(sArq, sNomeArquivo, "TEMP"), 5, 4))
    End If
    sArq = Dir
Wend

If (bSalvarPDF) Then
    sArq = Dir(Trim(sPath) & Trim(sNomeArquivo) & "????.PDF")
    While sArq <> ""
        If Val(Mid(Replace(sArq, sNomeArquivo, "TEMP"), 5, 4))  iNumero Then
            iNumero = Val(Mid(Replace(sArq, sNomeArquivo, > "TEMP"), 5, 4))
        End If
        sArq = Dir
    Wend
End If
sArq = Trim(sPath) & sNomeArquivo & Right("0000" & iNumero + 1, 4) & "." & sExtensao

Call MsgBox(sArq, vbOKOnly, "Arquivo")

oFile.CopyFile rst!EXC_Arq, sArq
oExcel.Workbooks.Open sArq
oExcel.Calculation = xlManual
```

It gives me the following error:

> Error 1004 'file.xlsx' could not be found.

My log warns that the error is at the following line:

```
oExcel.Workbooks.Open sArq
```

Also, my variable `sArq` gives the following result:
`C:\DOCUME~1\GAtec\CONFIG~1\Temp\TST 020005.XLS`  and sometimes `.XLSX` too

My current machine has Excel 2007 which supports .xlsx

Any leads?

Comment: Yep. Put file inside folder )))

Comment: What is your question? It sounds like you have already debugged it. Is the file there or not?

Comment: The file is there but it doesn't open.. and since it can't open with oExcel.Workbooks.Open then i can't keep adding values to the excel..

Comment: Is this really VB6 code or VBA?

Comment: The error message is probably correct. Something is wrong with the file path or filename, or its a typo or something.

Comment: I would add some MEssageBox calls to dump out variables as it runs (like sArq especially), or break in the debugger and see what is going on.